# Handling Imagemagick error in Bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, imagemagick

I am running a shell script that loops over 12,000 images comparing each to its twin image in another directory. The problem is when the twin image does not exist, Imagemagick just dies and reports an error, but I can't get a handle on it to make a log entry on the error.

Code I try:

```
#!/bin/bash

compare -metric AE -fuzz 1% /opt/fotos/239413.bmp /opt/fotos/549005.bmp -compose Src imgdiff.bmp
result="$?"

if [ "$result" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Your command exited with non-zero status $result"
fi

exit 0
```

Here is where the problem is, because ImageMagick returns

```
compare-im6.q16: image widths or heights differ `/opt/fotos/239413.bmp' @ error/compare.c/CompareImageCommand/1000.
```

Now, I am expecting for $result to contain that string, but bash is expecting 0-255. Just to let you know the command itself works perfect when images are there to compare returning a the number of pixels that are different so the command is working as desired.

It's just when an error occurs and Imagemagick dies. So where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You already have the handle when the command fails. You can add an `echo` to write to your log about the error. Which is the problem? Which is the expected result?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If I test it, it works well, echo message with Your command... So where is the problem?

Comment: put `echo $result` after `result="$?"` and share the output of echo

Comment: You need to verify that both images exist before you do your compare and be sure that the widths and heights are the same for a simple compare. You can get the widths and heights using `convert image -format "%w" info:` and `convert image -format "%h" info:`. Put those values in variables. Then do an if test to check that they both exist and that the widths are the same and that the heights are the same. If you are sure the two corresponding images have the same width and height, then skip that part of the test and just test for the existence of both. See if [ -f image_file ], for existence.

Comment: Your conditional is wrong. Try if [ "$result" != "0" ]; You were comparing a string to a integer. You want to compare a string to a string. So put quotes about your 0 and change -ne to !=.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your log file, so I'll assume it's $logfile. Save the error message by capturing stderr:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/myscript.err.XXXXXX)
compare -metric AE -fuzz 1% /opt/fotos/239413.bmp /opt/fotos/549005.bmp -compose Src imgdiff.bmp 2>"$tmpfile"

result="$?"

if [ "$result" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Your command exited with non-zero status $result"
    cat "$tmpfile" >> $logfile
fi
rm "$logfile"

exit 0
```

or if you really want result to contain the string, use

```
result=`cat "$logfile"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following code that I will use as the basis for my solution will explain what I was trying to do. I tested this and it is doing what I want but I must mention that I am considering implementing what user fmw42 has suggested, but will take this route for now.

Yes, I know the messages could change, but will deal with them as needed. Hope this helps somebody.

```
#!/bin/bash

compare_result=$(compare -metric AE -fuzz 1% /opt/fotos/239413A.bmp /opt/fotos/54900343.bmp -compose Src imgdiff.bmp 2>&1)

if echo "$compare_result" | grep -q "No such file or directory @"; then
    echo "No such file or directory was returned handle accordingly."
    exit 1
fi

if ! [[ "$compare_result" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "Compare returned an invalid integer: $compare_result"
    exit 1
fi

echo "The final result was: $compare_result"

exit 0
```